# Fade in and out on scroll, what if content already in view able area?

Tags: javascript, css

I have this code to fade in/out elements when scrolling a web page. The only problem is the stuff at the top of my page is faded out until you scroll. I want to check the visible area when the page loads and fade in the first visible items, how would I do this?

```
$(document).on("scroll", function () {
  var pageTop = $(document).scrollTop()
  var pageBottom = pageTop + $(window).height()
  var tags = $("section")

  for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    var tag = tags[i]

    if ($(tag).position().top < pageBottom) {
      $(tag).addClass("visible")
    } else {
      $(tag).removeClass("visible")
    }
  }
})
```

```
section {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 20px); 
  transition: all 1s;
}

section.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check for page ready and on scroll separately and call a function to make the section visible. (I added margin-bottom:20px; to the section css only for demo purposes). **Run code snippet** at bottom to see it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    setVisibility();
});


$(document).on("scroll", function () {
 setVisibility();
});

function setVisibility() {
  var pageTop = $(document).scrollTop()
  var pageBottom = pageTop + $(window).height()
  var tags = $("section")

  for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    var tag = tags[i]

    if ($(tag).position().top < pageBottom) {
      $(tag).addClass("visible")
    } else {
      $(tag).removeClass("visible")
    }
  }
}
```

```css
section {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 20px); 
  transition: all 1s;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

section.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</section>
  
<section>Donec convallis aliquam eros.</section>
  
<section>Morbi ac consectetur enim.</section>
  
<section>Maecenas mattis vestibulum consectetur.</section>
  
<section>Quisque vitae aliquam nisl.</section>
  
<section>Lacinia ut magna vel efficitur.</section>

<section>Vivamus in placerat nibh, eget fringilla arcu.</section>

<section>Mauris id mauris sed odio consequat efficitur</section>

<section>Duis elementum nulla nec mauris suscipit accumsan.</section>

<section>interdum velit id, tempor enim.</section>

<section>Duis iaculis consequat massa.</section>

<section>In vel risus id sem finibus consectetur</section>
```